# LIKE in python lambda expression

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do some validation of my data. I want to check if each tab contains proper columns and then validate their types. Validation should fail if my tab contains less columns than expected. On the other hand, if the tab contains more columns, I want to extract only the ones that I am interested in.

What I am doing right now, is to get those columns based on my schema. However, I don't want to have white spaces and any other additional characters in my dataframe.

Assuming my file has the following headers:

```
Red Carpet, Blue Carpet,Black Carpet(discounted)
```

My solution doesn't work for the last column. I know I can use additional function with regex but can I do it within my lambda expression as well? Or is it a bad practice?

```
schema = pandas_schema.Schema([
        Column('Red_Carpet', string_validation),
        Column('Blue_Carpet', string_validation),
        Column('Black_Carpet', string_validation)])

data_file_one = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=tab_name,usecols= lambda x: x if x.replace(" ", "_") in schema.get_column_names() else None))

errors = schema.validate(data_file_one)
```

Comment: Generally lambdas should be simple, so at the very least I would make a function `def` to pass as the argument to `usecols`. At that point it will be much easier to account for more corner cases. Regex is probably the most flexible approach here in either the lambda or the function style.